# jQuery - get file input element?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following markup:

```
  <div class="file-container">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  />
  </div>
```

I can get the uploaded file in my handler and ajax call as follows:

```
 $(document).on("change", ".file-container :file", function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "xyz",
        type: "POST",
        files: $("form :file"),
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).complete(function (data) {
       // do stuff

    });
});
```

But lets say i have two file inputs as follows:

```
 <div class="file-container">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"  />
 </div>

 <div class="file-container">
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"  />
 </div>
```

On `file1` change, how do i get the file element of file1 in my jQuery onchange handler and ajax call i.e what do i change this line to:

```
$(document).on("change", ".file-container :file", function ()
```

And this line:

```
files: $("form :file"),
```

The following doesnt work:

```
  $(document).on("change", ".file-container #file1", function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "xyz",
        type: "POST",
        files: $("form #file1"),
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).complete(function (data) {
       // do stuff

    });
  });

  $(document).on("change", ".file-container #file2", function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "xyz",
        type: "POST",
        files: $("form #file2"),
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).complete(function (data) {
       // do stuff

    });
});
```

Comment: Using inline `onchange` event for each input could be one approach of distinguishing which input was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `$(this)`

So this line:

```
 files: $("form :file"),
```

becomes

```
 files: $(this),
```

and the other stays as is.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".file-container :file", function () {

    console.log($(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-container">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"  />
 </div>

 <div class="file-container">
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"  />
 </div>
```

If you want separate handlers, you may as well just use the id's

```js
$(document).on("change", "#file1", function () {

  console.log("file1 handler",$(this))
});

$(document).on("change", "#file2", function () {

  console.log("file2 handler",$(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-container">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"  />
 </div>

 <div class="file-container">
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"  />
 </div>
```

Comment: what if I want to use a named file input in my onchange event handler  so that i can use two handlers - the reason being is that the ajax results for the two inputs do vary different things? So what would i change this bit too `.file-container :file`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the value of the input field (the selected filepath) does not change if you select the same file again.

You can set the value in the `onChange()` event to an empty string and submit your form only if the value is not empty. Have a look at my sample and this link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TmUmG/)

**Sample**

```
 $(document).on("change",".file-container input.file", function () {
    if ($(".file-container input.file").val() == "") {
        return;
    }
    // get the inputs value
    var fileInputContent = $(".file-container input.file").val();
    // your ajax submit
    alert("submit value of the file input field=" + fileInputContent);
    // reset the field
    $(".file-container input.file").replaceWith('<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />');
});​
```